# Page numbers on content page

Tags: page-numbering

The code I used to get roman numbers for front matter and arabic for chapters is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{epsfig}

\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{manfnt}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{subfigure}
% \usepackage{fancyheadings}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{epstopdf, bm}
\usepackage{epsfig,subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% \chaptertitlefont{\normalfont}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newcommand{\chapfnt}{\fontsize{16}{19}}
\newcommand{\secfnt}{\fontsize{14}{17}}
\newcommand{\ssecfnt}{\fontsize{12}{14}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\centering\normalfont\chapfnt\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\chapfnt}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\secfnt\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\ssecfnt\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{0pt}{10pt}
\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{0pt}{5pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection} {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib} 
\newcommand{\nat}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{N}}}
\newcommand{\zee}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Z}}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Q}}}
\newcommand{\R}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}}
\newcommand{\rtwo}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}^{2}}}
\newcommand{\rthree}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}^{3}}}
\newcommand{\filt}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{F}}}
\newcommand{\prob}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{P}}}
\newcommand{\Ti}{\ensuremath{T_i}}
\newcommand{\Tii}{\ensuremath{T_{i+1}}}
\newcommand{\pspace}{\ensuremath{(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})}}
\linespread{2}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newgeometry{
    top=1in,
    bottom=1in,
    outer=1in,
    inner=1in,
}


\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}

\begin{minipage}{0.75\linewidth}
    \centering
%University logo
    %\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{logo.pdf}
    % \rule{0.4\linewidth}{0.15\linewidth}\par
    % \vspace{3cm}
%Thesis title
    {\uppercase{\normal Title
   }}
    \vspace{3cm}
%Author's name
    {\normal by \\
    \vspace{1cm}
    Name\par}
    
    
    \vspace{3cm}
%Degree
    {\...
\par}

    \vspace{1cm}
    {\normal July 2021\\}
    \vspace{1cm}
    {\normal  
    ...
\par}
{\date{}}
   
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\pagenumbering{roman}
\chapter*{Acknowledgement}

\chapter*{Abstract}

\chapter*{Public Abstract}

\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
\input{chapters/chapter01}
\end{document}
```

This is what I see on the content page:

[image]

As you can see, the first chapter starts at page 2, and not 1. My table of contents has 3 pages. For some reason the first two pages are assigned roman numbers and the last page is assigned the arabic number 1. So page 1 of my thesis is the last page of the table of contents. Can you help me fix this?

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. What is your complete code .tex? I see only a fragment.

Comment: @Sebastiano I edited the question. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: It is a pleasure to help you. I have added the missing  \end{document}.

Comment: Rule number 1: don't ignore compilation errors. (i.e., the problem isn't that chapter ends up on page 2; the problem is that the code compiles with errors)

Comment: After the table of contents, insert `\clearpage`.  That will avoid resetting the page number too soon, which is what is happening here.  (`\tableofcontents` is not clearly scoped at the end.  Design flaw or intentional choice, I don't know, but resetting the numeration to arabic takes effect at once, which, in this case, is too soon.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton you are a life saver! Worked like magic

Comment: The `book` class has two commands that take care of this in a different way -- `\frontmatter` sets up the roman numeration, and `\mainmatter` starts a new page and restarts page numbering with arabic 1.  That is a good thing to remember, and it's really more obvious than just resetting the numeration.  But I don't remember whether it's defined in `report`.  (When you are under less pressure, you might want to look into that possibility.)

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately.